# Linear Algebra :: Multiplying by Matrices on both sides of equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering, for scalar equations, it is true that $A=B$ implies $PA=PB$ where P is also any scalar. Are these true for matrices as well?

Is $PAx=Pb$ true when $Ax=b$?

Assume that dimensions match up etc.

I was wondering about this since I read that elementary row operations preserve solutions of linear equations.

My intuition is that this is true since the matrix P will simply create linear combinations of the original equations and equate them but I am not sure what happens in general

Comment: Yes. In general, this is true for any well-defined function. If $x = y$, $f(x) = f(y)$. The converse may not be true though.

Answer (score 2):

If $Ax=b$ you have that $Ax-b$ is zero matrix. Then, as $P\cdot 0=0$ ($0$=zero matrix), for any $P$, we have that $P(Ax-b)$ is also zero matrix and therefore $PAx=Pb$

Answer (score 0):

If $A=B$, then the formula $PB = PB = PA$ follows immediately by substitution.

This works for pretty much any algebraic identity. It is always trivially true that you can multiply by both sides. What is not always the case however is that cancellation laws apply ($PA=PB \implies A=B$).

Comment: Your statement is wrong. Suppose we have $A=B$ for $m\times n$ matrices $A,B$. It makes sense to multiply by any $\ell\times m$ matrix $P$. If $\ell\ge m$ and the nullspace of $P$ is trivial (consists just the zero vector), then $PA=PB$ implies $A=B$. When $\ell<m$, certainly $P$ will never be invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. I adjusted my answer accordingly.